# Color of svg image stopped showing in teams message - adaptive card

Tags: svg, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have an azure function which sends a Teams message each time a new release has been succesfully deployed. It shows all delivered work items: bugs and stories. Until a few months ago the icons I have in my message showed color. It has stopped doing so, it shows only a black color. The url of the images still shows the correct image and color so there's nothing wrong with that.

Has something changed for the Teams renderer or do I need to adjust my adaptive card template?

The following is my template:

```
    {
  "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "contentUrl": null,
      "content": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "version": "1.3",
        "msteams": {
          "width": "Full"
        },
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "size": "Large",
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "${ReleaseTitle}",
                    "weight": "Bolder"
                  }
                ],
                "width": "stretch"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "auto",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "[Go to query](${QueryUrl})",
                    "isSubtle": true,
                    "height": "stretch"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "$when": "${ShowAdditionalQuery == true}",
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "auto",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "[additional query](${AdditionalQueryUrl})",
                    "isSubtle": true,
                    "height": "stretch"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "separator": true,
            "text": "",
            "type": "TextBlock"
          },
          {
            "$when": "${$root.UserStories.Count > 0}",
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "Image",
                    "url": "https://tfsprodweusu4.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItemIcons/icon_book?v=2&color=0098C7",
                    "width": "20px"
                  }
                ],
                "width": "auto"
              },
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "User Stories",
                    "weight": "Bolder"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$when": "${$root.UserStories.Count > 0}",
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 4,
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "[${WorkItemId} - ${Title}](${Url})",
                    "isSubtle": true
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 1,
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "${State}",
                    "isSubtle": true
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "$data": "${$root.UserStories}"
          },
          {
            "$when": "${$root.Bugs.Count > 0}",
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "Image",
                    "url": "https://tfsprodweusu4.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItemIcons/icon_insect?v=2&color=CC293D",
                    "width": "20px"
                  }
                ],
                "width": "auto"
              },
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Bugfixes",
                    "weight": "Bolder"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$when": "${$root.Bugs.Count > 0}",
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 4,
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "[${WorkItemId} - ${Title}](${Url})",
                    "isSubtle": true
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 1,
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "${State}",
                    "isSubtle": true
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "$data": "${$root.Bugs}"
          }
        ]
      }

    }
  ]
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you please share the public url of the icons(image). So that we can check it locally at our end.

Comment: This should be the public URL. https://tfsprodweusu4.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItemIcons/icon_book?v=2&color=0098C7

Comment: We are able to repro this issue. We have raised a bug for the same. We will let you know if there are any updates.

Comment: Any news on this one @Meghana-MSFT?

Comment: We do not have any update to share as of now, we will keep you posted.

Comment: Due to restrictions in the backend code regarding allowable SVG formats, engineering team has instructed to use the following URL, 
https://tfsprodweusu4.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItemIcons/icon_book?color=0098C7&v=2

Team will also make backend changes to accommodate either format, so it isn't restricted to this format.

Comment: Ok, switching positions of the v and color querystring parameter seems to do the trick. Weird but ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Meghana-MSFT:

Changing the position of the "v" and "color" querystring parameter fixes the issue.

e.g.
Old (not working - no color)
https://tfsprodweusu4.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItemIcons/icon_book?v=2&color=0098C7

New (working - with color)
https://tfsprodweusu4.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItemIcons/icon_book?color=0098C7&v=2